# Objects as instance variables - where to use new operator

Tags: java

I'm in the v.early stages of learning java.

I've been completing some practice exercises, and have some confusion around using instance variables to store objects, specifically creating "new" instances of those.

One beginner level exercise asks me to set up a project to enable ticket bookings to take place at a venue. I've been asked to set up the following:

i) An enumerated type to represent the type of a single event to be staged at the venue.

ii) A (simple) class Date that represents the date of the event.

iii) A (simple) class Price that represents the price of a ticket.

iv) A (simple) class Venue with a public method getSeatingCapacity(), which returns the capacity of a venue.

I got stuck specifically on this question:

Next, implement a class Event to represent a single event.
i) Identify and implement fields and constructor(s) you will need (see the above);

v) Use your answer to a) ii) to represent the date of the event;

vi) Use your answer to a) iii) to represent the ticket price;

vii) Use your answer to a) iv) to represent the venue.

The given answer is as follows:

```
public class Event

{
   private EventType eventType;
   private String eventTitle;
   private int numberOfAvailableTickets;
   private Date eventDate;
   private Price ticketPrice;
   private Venue venue;

public Event(EventType typeOfEvent, String titleOfEvent, Venue venue, Date dateOfEvent, Price priceOfTicket)
   {
       eventType = typeOfEvent;
       eventTitle = titleOfEvent;
       this.venue = venue;
       eventDate = dateOfEvent;
       ticketPrice = priceOfTicket;
       numberOfAvailableTickets = venue.getSeatingCapacity();
    }
```

However, my answer is as follows:

```
    private Venue location;
    private String title;
    private int totalTickets;
    private EventType genre;
    private Date date;
    private Price price; 

public Event(String title, int totalTickets, EventType genre)
    {
        location = new Venue();
        this.title = title;
        this.totalTickets = totalTickets
        this.genre = genre; 
        price = new Price(90);
        date = new Date("");
    }
```

I thought that I had to create instances of each of those objects in the constructor, by using the new operator otherwise how would they get created? And then I could use set methods to set new values. But it seems that's wrong? Can anyone help to elaborate?

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Comment: Initializing fields by constructor parameter or by object creation in the constructor are both valid solutions for different use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you'd set the values of those instance parameters in a couple of ways:

- Initialize them by passing the values as parameters to the constructors.
- Initialize them by creating new instances with default values inside your constructor (e.g. `new Date()` creates a new date from the current system timestamp).
- Initialize them in the initializer block or during declaration.

Setters are normally used to change the values, e.g. when setting a new date or a new price. A common approach would be to leave the instance variables with a null value and use a setter to change those that need to be changed.

Note that variables of non-primitive types (e.g. everything that's not an `int`, `long` etc.) are references to other objects, so basically when you set them you reference objects that exist elsewhere. Using `new` to create a new instance of an object would just do that and return a reference to that new instance, i.e. `Date date = new Date()` would first create a new instance of `Date` on the heap and then assign the reference to that instance to the variable `date`.

Since I assume you're not quite familiar with initializer blocks, here's what I mean:

```
class SomeClass {
  private int i; //will be initialized to 0
  private Date date; //will be initialized to null
  private String s = "hello"; //will create a new String object with the value "hello" and assign that instance to variable s

  //the following block is an instance initializer block which is called before the constructor
  {
    date = new Date();
  }

  //This is a static initializer block which is called when the class is loaded,
  //but which cannot be used to initialize instances
  static 
  {
    System.out.println("class has been loaded");
  }
}
```

Comment: Overusing setters and getters means defeating the purpose of OO programming - you are simply breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: @slnowak of course that's always something to think about but since the OP is new to Java I'd leave those more advanced topics for now ;)

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. But I remember the time I was learning java basics and OO programming - they simply told me to use setters/getters to access properties and at the same time they were talking about encapsulation. Which of course, doesn't match at all. So I think OP should be aware of this.

Comment: Thanks so much Thomas - very clear and patient! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that multiple events may take place in the same `Venue`. In that case, multiple `Event` objects can use the same `Venue` object. In your code, each `Event` would have a unique `Venue` object. Your approach would be more suitable if `Venue` was a unique property of the `Event` (i.e. not shared by other `Event`s).

Therefore, it makes more sense to either pass a `Venue` object to the constructor of `Event` or to have a `setVenue` method that would accept a `Venue` object.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid in this is a very simple example you have here but imagine the situation where the `Price` class for example had a more complex setup requiring information you didn't have access to in the `Event` contructor.

You would then have to set a dummy price and again have use the `setPrice()` to correct that. This requries an extra step that could be avoided by passing the already initialized object to the `Event` contructor.

I believe ultimately the benefit is to keep the constructor work simple and *relevant* to the class.